# extract two words before and after a character in python regex

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to extract two strings before and after a certain character[for example dot(.) ] in python regex

I tried extracting the table name after the dot, but couldn't figure out to extract the database name.

EDIT: There could be multiple dots in the query variable, but i want to extract the first occurrence.

```
import re
query = 'select * from xxx.yyy'
table_name = re.search('\.(.*)\s', query).group(1).split(" ",2)[0]
print table_name
```

output:

```
yyy
```

I expect the output to be either xxx.yyy or could be in a list is fine too, like [xxx,yyy].

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using pattern `'(\w+)\.(\w+)'`

**Ex:**

```
import re
query = 'select * from xxx.yyy'
table_name = re.search('(\w+)\.(\w+)', query)
print table_name.groups()
#or
print re.search('((\w*)\.(\w*))', query).group(0)
```

**Output:**

```
('xxx', 'yyy')
xxx.yyy
```

Comment: Awesome, this works. Can you please explain this code

Comment: @MohanramKrishnan. `\w+` --> matches atleast one alphanumeric character and the underscore. So the above regex will look for alphanumeric character before and after the dot

Comment: alphanumeric or underscore

Comment: @Rakesh, thanks for explaining. I assume this code works, even if we have multiple dot in the query string, and It would extract only the first occurrence. I tried and it extracted the first oocurrence. Just making sure.

Answer (score 0):

This can be handy in learning regular expressions and also to test them out.[regex101.com](https://regex101.com/)

This regex should solve your issue `[A-Za-z]+\.[A-Za-z0-9]+` 
A-Z - catch capital letters
a-z - catch small letters
0-9 - catch numbers

[Here is example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n8w8F.png)

Hope you find this helpful!